Romantic Comedy for men, guy is sad from breakup and cant get over ex, scene where all he can see is topless girls runs away in fear
Movie where the main actor is sad from breaking up from "the love of his life". He cant finish his "buisness" with any other girl but the ex. Tries to get over her but cant etc until he meets a new girl. After he meets this girl and they get close the ex ties him up and has sex with him which makes the new relationship fragile.
There is a specific scene i remember where the guy gets hit on by lots of sexy topless girls, billboards are pictured with boobs and he runs away in fear for some reason.
Its kindof a type of frat movie feel without having anything to do with school.
He lives with a guy that encourages him to get laid, and if i can remember correctly that guy never gets laid and is jealous of his looks.
End of movie scene when the girl and main actor have lots of sex, he walks into the kitchen and pours a gallon of water down his pants infront of the guy he lives with.
Movie is late 90's early 2000

Sounds like "40 Days and 40 Nights", from 2002.

Matt Sullivan's (Josh Hartnett) last big relationship ended in disaster and ever since his heart's been aching and his commitment's been lacking. Then came Lent, that time of year when everybody gives something up. That's when Matt decides to go where no man's gone before and make a vow: No sex. Whatsoever. For 40 straight days. At first he has everything under control. That is until the woman of his dreams, Erica (Shannyn Sossamon), walks into his life.

The specific scene you described with topless girls, you can see here.
